# How to change rspec's test path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I have an `admin` engine with rspec inside my `host` application. Here is the my application structure:

[image: Structure of my application]

Here is the my `admin` engine's config:

```
module Admin
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Admin
    engine_name 'admin'
    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: false, view_specs: false
      g.fixture_replacement :fabrication
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'
      g.integration_tool :rspec
      g.assets false
      g.helper false
    end
  end
end
```

When I create new controller inside the `admin` engine. I want to generate controller tests on `host` application's `spec/admin/controllers/welcome_controller_spec.rb`. I guess I need change `admin` engine's rspec's config.  Any idea?

Comment: It's not really an answer for your question, but assuming you are on *NIX, can't you just make a symlink from expected to desired location?  Symlinks can be checked into Git repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `admin` project, in `config/initializers` directory you can create a monkey patch to overwrite the path where the controller spec file is generated:

file **/config/initializers/scaffold_generator.rb**

```
require 'generators/rspec/scaffold/scaffold_generator'

module Rspec
  module Generators
    class ScaffoldGenerator

      def generate_controller_spec
        return unless options[:controller_specs]

        template 'controller_spec.rb',
                 File.join('/path/to/host/project', 'spec/admin/controllers', controller_class_path, "#{controller_file_name}_controller_spec.rb")
      end

    end
  end
end
```

It would be clever to replace the hard-coded path '/path/to/host/project' by something more dynamic, so it won't break when you move your workspace files in another location. I can't help you for that because it depends on your project file structure, and it should be easy to do.

To invoke:

```
bundle exec rails generate scaffold_controller my_controller
```

Will generate the controller, helper, views, rspec/helper, and rspec/views files in your `admin` project, and the rspec/controller file in your `host` project

Comment: Even if in your case you are not generating views, but I mentioned the generation of view files, to make my answer more general